# Adobe XD not able to install: error 191

Tags: cloud, creative

I am getting `error 191` while installing Adobe XD form the Creative Cloud:

```
Exit Code: 191
-------------------------------------- Summary --------------------------------------
 - 2 fatal error(s), 2 error(s), 0 warnings(s) 

FATAL: Error (Code = 191) executing in command 'AddUWPAppxCommand' for package: 'UWPAssets', version:16.0.2.8
FATAL: Error occurred in install of package (Name: UWPAssets Version: 16.0.2.8). Error code: '191'
ERROR: hdhelper exe at C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Adobe Desktop Common\HDBox\HDHelper.exe failed to install UWP app with xml 
    Adobe.CC.XD
    C:\adobeTemp\ETRB13C.tmp\1\SparklerApp\SparklerApp.appx
    16.0.2.8
    x64
    CN=Adobe Systems Incorporated, OU=Adobe Systems, O=Adobe Systems Incorporated, L=San Jose, S=California, C=US, SERIALNUMBER=2748129, OID.2.5.4.15=Private Organization, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US
    adbxd:


            Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00
            14.0.25426.0
            x64
            CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
            C:\adobeTemp\ETRB13C.tmp\1\SparklerApp\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx


        false


 with error code 1
ERROR: Failed to install UWP Appx Package
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with installing Adobe XD and tried every solution I could find. The one thing no one has written about was the following.

1. Open "Microsoft Store"
2. Open then menu on the top right hand corner and select "Downloads and Updates"
3. Run the updates. I updated every app but i think "App Installer" or "Microsoft Store" should be the crutial ones.
4. Restart your PC
5. Install Adobe XD

I hope, this solution works for you as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue while installing Adobe XD and I tried everything that I could possibly find on the Internet and nothing seemed to work for me. But I finally found the solution after 3 days of trial and errors.

1. Press Window key + R, type appwiz.cpl and press enter button.

You'll see the list of installed programs on your computer.

2. Scroll to Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable installations, you'll have a lot of them ( I had  programs from 2005 to 2019)  Right click on each one individually and click on MODIFY, then press REPAIR. Repeat this for all the ones that has modify option.
3. Restart your computer, and install again It'll be installed this time.

NOTE : I tried everything from  [Adobe help for error 191](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/download-install/kb/error-code-191.html)and then did this at last to fix my problem.
Hope that Helps,Regards!
Sreenath

Answer (score 0):

I tried all mentioned previously. I can fixed and installed Xd through to repair Creative Cloud.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `appwiz.cpl` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> button.
2. Select Adobe Creative Cloud then clic right and select Desinstall/Change
3. A window will appear ask you for to uninstall or repai. Select repair
4. Click repair and wait. After this you can select Adobe Xd and install wihtout errors

Answer (score 0):

If you've used a third-party program or regedit scripts to disable "AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC)" on system launch, this error may rise as well. You cannot traditionally set the start option of this service via Services (services.msc), so what you need to do is:

1. `Win + R` to bring up `Run`.
2. `regedit` and hit `OK` to bring up `Registry Editor`.
3. Navigate to the key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AppXSvc`
4. Double-click `Start` on right panel, and set its value to `2`.
5. Restart your  computer.

This will likely fix "Adobe error 191", as well as system wide error 0x80070422, example as such: "ERROR: Failed to install UWP Appx Package ... OS_Error_Code: 0x80070422#@#OS_Error_String: The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it."

**P.S. for additional info:** To be more specific, 0x80070422 is raised when a service cannot be traditionally started on demand, but only per startup due to privileges. If you receive this error code, it is likely you have disabled a service via Registry Editor (regedit).

While in this case it is due to Adobe XD being a UWP app, and AppXSVC is responsible for enabling that feature, if that's not the case for you, it could as well be Windows Event Log collector, or Windows Update, depending on which service is trying to be ran.